# StatusBar over ion-nav on ionic 3

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, ionic3

Why my statusBar is over on ion-nav ?

My `home.html` is like this

```
<ion-header>
<ion-navbar color="royal">
  <button ion-button icon-only menuToggle>
    <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
  </button>
  <ion-title>
    Empreendimentos
  </ion-title>
</ion-navbar>
```

And `app.components.ts` is like this

```
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';


initializeApp() {
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
  // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
  // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
  this.statusBar.overlaysWebView(true);
  this.statusBar.backgroundColorByHexString('#4a148c');
  this.splashScreen.hide();
});
```

}

And this is a status bar on my app

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have solved as follows

```
this.statusBar.overlaysWebView(false);
```